# How can a class be added to a div via php?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, class, addition

I have this h tag below,

```
<h3 id="reply-title">
```

& I needed to add a class to it remotely.

(This h3 tag is located in comment-template.php. (line 1554) of WordPress core file in case you are wondering why I can't just hard code the class to it.)

I've done this with one line jQuery (add class on .load) but now, I am concerned since if javascript is turned off, the class won't be added.

I have very little knowledge of php and I am wondering if this can be done in php.  I've done some research on google & I couldn't find any reference.

Any php expert who can provide some insight?

Comment: Your `<div>` looks a lot like an `<h3>`.

Comment: Today, most of sites uses javascript, don't afraid about the javascript turn off

Comment: use child themes to customize the file

Comment: The problem is, "most" doesn't cut it.  I wouldn't worry about it either if this is my personal blog.  I just need a fail proof method.

Comment: @ Tamil Selvan, I don't know how a child theme's comments.php can modify the core file.  I don't know of single child theme that does that.  That comment-template.php isn't a part of a theme file but part of core WP file.

Comment: Deleted my answer then, though I believe such a thing as a template should not reside in the core (you can suggest WP to move it to the themes folder)..

Answer (score 0):

This is in general a bad practice, but you can do that like this:

```
echo "<script>$('#reply-title').addClass('class')</script>";
```

But I repeat: **This is a bad practice**. The Javascript must be in .js files, and the PHP in .php files.

However, if the Javascript is disabled, I think you can't do what you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is more or less what I've done. :D

My question is how to avoid using that jQuery to add class.

Maybe this isn't possible w/o using jQuery?  But I can't believe that php doesn't have the ability to do what jQuery can do in one line of code.

I am inclined to think there's gotta be a way.

Comment: Remember that PHP if for server-side. Your request is for the client-side, and this is the Javascript's Job.

Comment: Yefb, I am not sure if I understand you clearly.  Are you saying that adding a class to a div takes place only on client-side?

I think maybe you are correct on that now I think about it.  :D

Comment: Yes, Yefb, I am pretty sure you are correct on that more I think about it. LOL

Thanks for your comment & clearing my head.

Comment: @Matthew If you need that class to trigger a JS function, adding it with JS isn't technically a bad practice.